# Combining records using Hive window frame

Tags: sql, hive

I am having a following query which is executed in Hive for a single date. But the table is having massive number of rows containing dudate from 2000 onwards. I want to create a window function for this dudate for previous day and previous week. Basically trying to convert this query including all dates dynamically using window function.

**SQL**

```
    SELECT R.rmid as rid, '2021-05-30' as pdate, Sum(odn) as Odn, Sum(gdn) as gdn, Sum(wdn) as wdn,0 as podn,0 as pgdn,0 as pwdn,0 as aodn,0 as agdn,0 as awdn
FROM table1 as cd
inner Join table2 c on c.mid = cd.mid
inner join table3 rsi on rsi.omid = c.mid and rsi.omtype = 1
inner join table4 rs on rs.rsmid = rsi.rsmid
inner join table5 r on r.rmid = rs.rmid
WHERE cd.dudate = date('2021-05-30')
GROUP BY R.rmid,pdate
Union
SELECT R.rmid as rid,'2021-05-30' as pdate, 0 as Odn,0 as gdn,0 as wdn,Sum(odn) as podn, Sum(gdn) as pgdn, Sum(wdn) as pwdn,0 as aodn,0 as agdn,0 as awdn
FROM table1 as cd
inner Join table2 c on c.mid = cd.mid
inner join table3 rsi on rsi.omid = c.mid and rsi.omtype = 1
inner join table4 rs on rs.rsmid = rsi.rsmid
inner join table5 r on r.rmid = rs.rmid
WHERE cd.dudate = date_add('2021-05-30', -1)
GROUP BY R.rmid,pdate
Union
SELECT R.rmid as rid,'2021-05-30' as pdate,0 as Odn,0 as gdn,0 as wdn,0 as podn,0 as pgdn,0 as pwdn,Sum(odn)/7 as aodn, Sum(gdn)/7 as agdn, Sum(wdn)/7 as awdn
FROM table1 cd
inner Join table2 c on c.mid = cd.mid
inner join table3 rsi on rsi.omid = c.mid and rsi.omtype = 1
inner join table4 rs on rs.rsmid = rsi.rsmid
inner join table5 r on r.rmid = rs.rmid
WHERE cd.dudate BETWEEN date_add('2021-05-30', -7) AND date_add('2021-05-30', -1)
GROUP BY R.rmid
```

Basically combining all rows for given date, previous day and 7 days before records.

Can anyone provide me an idea how to union values in windowframes?